# FasterXML Jackson?

Tags: java, json

I'm switching to jackson json because it's apparently faster than minimal-json. I am however confused to how it works as the documentation is confusing.

Is it:
`import com.fasterxml.jackson...`
or:
`import org.codehaus.jackson...`

I have tried both, I have the file `jackson-core-2.5.0.jar` and the `import com.fasterxml.jackson` works, however I am not able to do the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Comment: You need `com.fasterxml.jackson-core:jackson-databind:2.5.0`

Comment: What does _I am not able to do the following_ mean?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You know what it means, stop playing dumb ;) The object ObjectMapper is not recognized.

Comment: Always include such information, with its exact error message.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Feel sorry for you if you require(or don't understand) such information for such an obvious error setting. Wasting time in software development isn't what I'm here to do.

Comment: It's not about not understanding or wasting time, etc. Stack Overflow is not _for you_. It's for everyone. If you put all the relevant information and not leave room for interpretation, you'll get better answers, your question will be indexed better and therefore it will be easier for people to find it. You can choose not to, fine, but I suggest you do.

Comment: Assuming things and not being specific is bad practice across wide array of disciplines. It has very little to do with software but rather problem solving in general. Imagine going into a car forum and saying "I was driving my car and it stopped working please fix it.. Oh its Ford.. Come on You know what the problem is"... That was basically your question.

Comment: @AdamGent Are you seriously comparing cars to programming? I mentioned a line of code that did not work which is common to write in Jackson, I also pointed out possibilities of what could be wrong (the package). In car terms it should be, "I was driving my car and it stopped working. A light stating the engine has overheated is blinking, I don't know if the radiator is broken of I need to refill it with more coolant." *That* was basically my question. Also Sotirios also answered fully including additional information, so apparantly it was clear enough for him.

Comment: @KarlMorrison You had to state in a comment "*The object ObjectMapper is not recognized*" for SotiriosDelimanolis and myself to figure out your problem. And then afterwards you insult someone trying to help you. Any number of things could have happen besides compile errors for "*I am not able to do the following: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();*". Its like saying I'm not able to start the car. ObjectMapper could have thrown an exception. You could have the incorrect dependencies (ie an old JDK). Even saying it makes a red squiggle line in Eclipse would have been more helpful.

Comment: @AdamGent I am sorry if you feel like I've insulted him, that's your thoughts. Had to and had to is your personal opinion. Again it is more like "I am not able to start the car because either the radiator is broken or I need to fill it with more coolant", where would you look, yes of course, at the radiator as I so happened to point out (in the case of the question, the packages) in which where the problem did reside. I am running Android Studio with my own personalized specific color scheme with the latest JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jackson 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150525213857/http://jackson.codehaus.org:80/) was part of `org.codehaus`. [Jackson 2](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki) is now part of `com.fasterxml` and [is in no way backwards compatible](https://web.archive.org/web/20170903180439/http://wiki.fasterxml.com:80/JacksonRelease20).

The [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) type is in the package [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/package-summary.html).

Comment: Ahh, perfect thanks mate. The documentation is pretty confusing now that they have changed, you cleared it all up now!